# Как подключить свойство transform для семейства ie?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css3, transform

Есть у меня сайтом с аналогичным эффектом раскрывающихся лепестков в первом экране, как на [этом сайте](http://infostart.ru/). 
Все бы ничего, но для в случае переворота кружка в обратную сторону во всех браузерах семейства IE (даже самых последних) текст отзеркаливается и выводится наоборот за счет того, что они не воспринимают свойство `transform`.. Подключил [modernizr](https://modernizr.com/) и даже это не спасает.

```
.ring-body-root.active .ch-item .ch-info {
    -webkit-transform: rotate3d(0,1,0,-180deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate3d(0,1,0,-180deg);
    -o-transform: rotate3d(0,1,0,-180deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate3d(0,1,0,-180deg);
    transform: rotate3d(0,1,0,-180deg);
}
```

По идее это недоразумение должен исправлять `filter`, но, к примеру, [этот онлайн генератор](http://demos.aimweb.name/css-transform-generator/) для моего случая не срабатывает. 
Может есть каике либо другие полноценные генераторы или кого-либо другие идеи вроде подключения нужных полифилов?

Answer (score 1):

Есть такие библиотеки как [CSS3 Pie](http://css3pie.com/) или более [старый вариант](http://fetchak.com/ie-css3/), когда подключаешь их и они автоматически конвертируют стили под старые версии IE.

Comment: работает только для `border-radius`, `box-shadow`, `linear-gradient`, но не для `transform: rotate`

Comment: к слову, даже подключение `modernizr` ничего не дает

Comment: @Вася, на сколько я знаю большего вы не добьетесь. Добавлю так же что зря вы сейчас мучаетесь с старыми IE. IE 9 поддерживает большинство возможностей CSS 3 и установлен на большинстве старых компьютеров. В эпоху Windows 10 c нормальным личным браузером ничто не грозит вам писать в стандартном виде, не заботясь о несовместимости. В плане если кто-то использует IE 7 то этот человек настолько отстал в прогрессе, что ему не стоит даже разрешать загружать страничку сайта =)

Comment: так мы никуда и не сдвинулись вообще-то.. 
О каком ie7 речь? ie11 не поддерживает, который установлен на большинстве windows 7-8, которыми все пользуются - 10ок с edgem малый процент пользователей

Comment: @Вася, [таблица совместимости](http://htmlbook.ru/css/transform)

Comment: там не просто `rotate`, а `rotate3d` и `perspective`, которые даже последними ie не поддерживаются..

Comment: @Вася, transform 3d действительно поддерживается лишь 12-й версией IE. Но для подобных преобразований можно использовать 2d изменение. Например вы могли бы использовать [matrix](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/playit.asp?filename=playcss_transform_matrix).